# Button doesn’t pass through touches to collection view cell on iOS 14

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, contextmenu, ios13, ios14

I noticed some strange behavior.

I got `CollectionViewCell` and UIButton in its `contentView`.

I implemented `contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt` method, and it works fine on iOS 13. But when I try to test it on iOS 14, the button doesn’t pass through long press touches and handles them itself.

Any idea how to fix it, and why is it happening?

Please note that I prefer not having complicated logic in button’s `hitTest` or `pointInside` methods.

Answer (score 0):

"I don’t want complicated logic in button’s hitTest or pointInside methods" - I wish I could include laughing emojis. I would HIGHLY recommend utilizing `hitTest(:)` and `pointInside(:)` methods to directly control where button presses are going to be executed - especially since there could be changes from iOS versions, such as the problem you are having - OR if you end up changing your User Interface.

For example:

> `hitTest(:)` -- Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.

So, if you add a something behind the button, then the button will NO LONGER be the item that is tapped. Thus, you should seriously take control of this by implementing the related methods.

Comment: What i meant is if i do it, i wont be able to implement context menu on button for example. But what if i am using that one custom button all over my app and sometimes it should answer kn long press touches.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But do you know what changed in new ios version? I cant find any information about that, ant its confusing(

Comment: I have no idea -- and generally speaking, small mishaps happen like this all the time. The only thing we can do as 3rd party developers is attempt to guarantee our results; for example, with the methods above.

Comment: You can add long presses and gestures with actions that are taken as input from different view controllers - as well as remove gestures as needed